# While image loading TIC SSL Trust Error NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uiimageview, ssl-certificate

Our domain is very secure.. I am getting all images from json to cellForItemAt  but those images are not displaying in collectionView... and why I am getting this error in console while loading images in collectionview...

> TIC SSL Trust Error [2:0x600002dc5b00]: 3:0
>
> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
>
> Task <888B6BAC-34CB-4146-8283-916DDCA76CD4>.<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -1202 [3:-9843])
>
> NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1202

I have also added in my plist:

[image]

and also I have gone through this:   [How to fix ‘TIC SSL Trust Error’ in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974527/how-to-fix-tic-ssl-trust-error-in-ios)

and added this extension in my HomeViewController:

```
extension HomeViewController: URLSessionDelegate {
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    if (challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate) {
        completionHandler(.rejectProtectionSpace, nil)
    }
    if (challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust) {
        let credential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
    }
}
}
```

Why am I still unable to display images in collectionView? Please help me with this error.

Comment: actually, it's not from your XCode app .. anyway, my backend solves it ( he said - he removed auto-redirect from HTTP to HTTPS ). 
by the way - there are a lot of cases for this